# How to find the single gem installed when only specifying a Ruby version in a Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

I'm running Ruby 2.7.0, Bundler 2.1.4 and macOS 10.15.3.

I have a Gemfile in an otherwise empty folder which is only specifying the Ruby version:

```
ruby '2.7.0'
```

When I run `bundle`,  or `bundle install`, I get:

```
% bundle install
The Gemfile specifies no dependencies
Bundle complete! 0 Gemfile dependencies, 1 gem now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

However, `bundle list` gives me:

```
% bundle list
No gems in the Gemfile
```

What is the one installed gem? Where would I find it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Bundler itself.

These are the links to the code for the output from the `bundle install` command:

- https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/v2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb#L69
- https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/v2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb#L119-L122
- https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/v2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb#L180-L183

The important part is the last part where `specs["bundler"]` is empty then it assigns bundler spec to `specs["bundler"]` so `specs.count` returns at least `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

- `bundle show`
- `bundle show name_of_gem`